# 2 where statements in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

Iam having trouble creating a query. How to i create two where selects in one?

```
select * from messages where id ='1' and where recd = '0'
```

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use one `WHERE` clause only and the conditions are separated by `AND/OR` depending on your needs.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   messages 
WHERE  id ='1' AND recd = '0'
```

Answer (score 1):

TRy this::

```
select * from messages where id ='1' and recd = '0'
```

Answer (score 1):

If **id** and **recd** fields are numeric values you can/should avoid using **'(single quot)** for better index searching performance.

```
select * from messages where id = 1 and recd = 0;
```

MySQL is enough advanced to manage this string/numeric conversion in both current case of query.

Hope this will helpful.